# Existing software/scripts for spiral graphs?

Tags: software, visualization

I am looking for existing software or scripts to generate spiral graphs from cyclical (time) data, as presented by [Webber and Muller](http://ieg.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~aigner/teaching/ws06/infovis_ue/papers/spiralgraph_weber01visualizing.pdf).  The graphs shown in the paper look like a great means of visualizing and identifying periodicity in cyclical data, but I haven't been able to Google up any existing solutions for creating graphs like these.

Comment: The descriptions in the paper seem straightforward. But perhaps you could ask the authors directly for code.